# MySQL - Planning Cost Higher Than Number of Blocks Occupied in Disk

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization, mysql-5.7

There is a table `dept` and it has 100 rows, all nicely tucked in 1 block, as seen in the `mysql.innodb_index_stats` table.

| table_name | index_name | stat_name | stat_value | sample_size | stat_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dept | PRIMARY | size | 1 | NULL | Number of pages in the index |

After running the following query...

```sql
select * from dept;
```

..and looking at its optimizer trace, I see that in the row estimation phase, it says cost = **1** (reading 1 block), but in the planning phase, it says **21**. I do not know why and what is the calculation there.

[image]

The same happens for all tables. Another Example:

There is a table `student` and it has 100000 rows, tucked in 609 blocks, as seen in the `mysql.innodb_index_stats` table.

| table_name | index_name | stat_name | stat_value | sample_size | stat_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| student | PRIMARY | size | 609 | NULL | Number of pages in the index |

After running the following query...

```sql
select * from student;
```

..and looking at its optimizer trace, I see that in the row estimation phase, it says cost = **609** (reading 609 blocks), but in the planning phase, it says **20504**.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the IO cost, a compute cost is added.  This cost is `#rows * row_evaluate_cost`. By default `row_evaluate_cost = 0.2`.  In your case, the are 100 rows, so the compute cost will be `1 + 100*0.2 = 21`.

Answer (score 1):

When the Cost model was implemented, complained (to no avail) that it failed to take into effect

- Whether the data was likely to be cached in RAM.  (This makes a big difference.)
- Whether the disk is HDD or SSD.  (Possibly a factor of 10 on the cost.)

Hence, I mostly ignore "cost".  Instead, I look primarily at "number of rows (data and/or index) touched".  This is somewhat provided by

```
FLUSH STATUS;
run the query
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

This fails to note UUID indexes are likely to be very non-clustered as opposed to, say, a date range.

UUID (or hash) + huge table (to big to be cached in RAM) ==> Terrible Performance.